# Why is k called representer of evaluation in the definition of kernel functions

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, svm

Why is $k$ called *representor of evaluation*?
From the book "Learning with kernels" by Bernhard Schölkopf we have the following lines (page 33):

> $\langle k(.,x),f\rangle = f(x)$, in particular $\langle k(.,x), k(.,x')\rangle = k(x,x')$

According to the book this interesting property of $\phi$ follows from definition. How?

I am unable to understand this and this is crucial for understanding the concept of *reproducing kernel Hilbert spaces*. Any help appreciated.

Luckily, the part of the book which needs to be referred *i.e.* section 2.2.2 (starts on page 32) is a part of [the preview in Google books](http://books.google.be/books?id=y8ORL3DWt4sC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false). Also note that this section is independent of other sections.

Comment: seems to be close to info on "nonlinear kernel function" on this page? [support vector machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine#Nonlinear_classification)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When it says "follows directly from the definition", it means directly from the definition of $\langle -,- \rangle$, not directly from the definition of $\Phi$. Equation 2.24 on page 33 is a definition (that's why it uses the := notation instead of just an equals sign.) The definition says that if $f = \sum_i \alpha_i k(.,x_i)$ and $g = \sum_j \beta_j k(.,y_j)$ then $\langle f,g\rangle$ is *defined to be* $\sum_{i,j} \alpha_i \beta_j k(x_i, y_j)$. In particular, if $f=k(.,x)$ and $g=k(.,x')$ then the definiton in Equation 2.24 says that
$$\langle f, g \rangle = k(x,x')$$
(think of one $\alpha_i$ and one $\beta_j$ being $1$ and the rest $0$). This is Equation 2.30.

Equation 2.29 is similar but more general. Suppose we have some $f = \sum_j \beta_j k(.,x_j)$. Then
$$\langle k(,.x), f \rangle = \langle k(.,x), \sum\beta_j k(.,x_j) \rangle$$ 
and again Definition 2.24 says that this equals
$$\sum \beta_j k(x, x_j)$$
*by definition*. But this is just $f(x)$, so that gives (2.29).

Answer (score 3):

In an RKHS framework, any function $f(\cdot)$ can be minimized with a hilbert-norm minimizing solution, just by a linear combination of the kernels evaluated at the rest of the data points and $x$ itself.

i.e, in detail, if you dont know the result of the function $f's$ Hilbert-norm minimizing minimizer, all you need to do in a reproducing kernel Hilbert space, (RKHS) is that you take the reproducing p.s.d kernel $K(\cdot,\cdot)$ which is a function of two arguments (pairwise), where in one argument you fix $x$; the point where you would like to evaluate $f(\cdot)$ such that $x$ is the minimizer and then in the other argument you choose each of the other points apart from $x$ that you have in your dataset, as $K(x,\cdot)$ and then the "Representer Theorem" ensures that there exists a set of $\alpha's$ which go along with $K(x,\cdot)$ such that the result $f(x)$ "can be" represented/${evaluated}/admits$ the following property: $f(x)=\sum{K(x,\cdot)}$ where the placeholder $\cdot$ takes the rest of the data points and the summation is over each of those points.